# Missing output of a conditional statement on an xarray

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I have 5 years of NetCDF files with daily time step and running a conditional statement on the concatenated single file as following:

```
ds = xr.open_mfdataset('D:/*.nc', concat_dim='day')
da = ds.var.sel(lon=-79.1833333, lat=42.4, method='nearest')
con = da[(da >= 40.0) & (da <= 60.4)]
val = con.chunks
print(val[0])
```

It returns

```
(1,3,2,1)
```

Instead, I like it to return `0` for the year as well where the condition wasn't met (so the output should look like this `1,3,0,2,1`). Any suggestion to obtain all chunk outputs even if any of it is zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out -- not neat but works.

```
ds = xr.open_mfdataset('D:/*.nc', concat_dim='day')
da = ds.var.sel(lon=-79.1833333, lat=42.4, method='nearest')
con = da[(da >= 40.0) | (da <= 60.4)]
da_cnt = np.asarray(da.chunks[0]) - np.asarray(con.chunks[0]) # it returns years with zero values as well
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ds = xr.open_mfdataset('D:/*.nc', concat_dim='day')
da = ds.var.sel(lon=-79.1833333, lat=42.4, method='nearest')
da[~(da >= 40.0) & (da <= 60.4)] == 0 # if the assignment here doesn't work 
# then try using da.where()
con = da[((da >= 40.0) & (da <= 60.4) | (da = 0.))]
```

Comment: still missing years with zero values